# AutoAI is not appearing in IBM Watson Studio?

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I'm trying to make a new asset in IBM Watson Studio, but I cannot find AutoAI?

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Note: I have just created my account and started learning about IBM Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Studio is a framework of tooling which on its own doesn't give you very much. AutoAI is a part of the Machine Learning service, which you will need to create an instance of. Once created you will be able to use Watson Studio to access the Machine Learning service.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add AutoAI as an asset, you need to have both Watson Studio and Watson Machine Learning active and provisioned. NB, they both need to be set up for the same location (eg. Frankfurt).

If you think you might have set up something incorrectly, I'd suggest going to https://cloud.ibm.com/resources and deleting the instances you just created, and recreating them to ensure they linked to the same location.

With both Watson Machine Learning and Watson Studio set up correctly, AutoAI will appear under the New Asset page.